# Can I use power cord from old psu to new psu of same brand(Corsair cx650m to Corsair HX 750)

Tags: power-supply, power

I bought a new Corsair HX 750 psu recently and found out that the power cable that comes with the box has UK style 3 pin. But I have Indian style 3 pin connector to wall. Can I use the power cord from my old Corsair cx650m semi modular psu?

Comment: Yes because india is 230 volts as well

Comment: The 3-pin connector is very common, not special to that PSU.

Answer (score 1):

Cords are just cords. Both PSUs have the same C14 connector. What matters is the main power provided. Both India and UK work on 230V/50Hz, so yes, you can use the same power cord.